# Set ground reference of a 5v DC power supply to the middle of a 24v DC power supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, dc, switch-mode-power-supply, voltage-reference

I have 2 isolated AC/DC power supplies. one generates a regulated 5 volt power supply and other generates a 24 volt power supply as you can see in the picture below:

[image: two isolated DC power supplies]

I also have designed a circuit (the blue PCB above) that has analog parts that works with 24v and digital part that works with 5v. The analog part are some op-amps that I use for audio amplification so I need the GND reference of my audio (on my circuit) to be in the middle of the 24v. this reference GND is also used to be the GND of my digital circuit. so my main question is what is the best approach to set the GND of both 24v and 5v power supplies to be at exact middle of 24v rail. in other word, i have 2 pair of  isolated 5v and 24v cables and I want to have these signals: GND(0),-12,+12,+5

you can see the main question in the picture below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQoODy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

now the approches that I currently have in my mind is as follows:

1. use an op-amp:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0x85x.png)</sup>

2. use a 12 volt regulator (7812)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm2UJJ.png)</sup>

I wanted to know that if my approaches are OK? and if yes, which one is better? If there is a better way of doing this I would really appreciate any suggestions! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither work well.

The first is the right basic idea, but a normal opamp doesn't have enough power, so if your analog circuit dumps more than a few mA onto the GND connection, that exceeds the opamp's output current, and the opamp loses control so that GND is no longer halfway between the supplies.

The second one works if the analog circuit pulls current out of GND (think of a resistor between GND and -12V) but not if it sources current into GND (resistor between GND and +12V). In the latter case, GND will be pulled up towards the +12V rail.

If you use the first idea, but replace the opamp with an amplifier capable of supplying 1 Amp (or whatever your PSU is rated for, you didn't say) you have a good basis for a solution. (Add a decoupling capacitor across each of R1 and R2 to reduce noise). But such an amplifier may be quite expensive and require a heatsink.

Frankly the simplest solution is separate +12V and -12V supplies.

Comment: Add to Brian's comments that if you have bypass capacitors on your +/-12V rails to "ground", the op-amp will almost surely oscillate at a high frequency. If you put a power resistor from -12V to GND the 7812 would work so long as the current through the power resistor was high enough to soak up any difference in favor of current from +12 to GND. If not, the rails would go out of regulation.

Comment: Thank you Brian for your answer. about your simplest solution though! you meant that instead of a 24v AC/DC power supply i use two different 12v power supply and tie the points together as a GND and have 3 other points as +5, -12 and +12?
about the analog circuit current I need to assure 1000mA current.

Comment: Thanks Spehro! so let's assume i want to have 1A current assurance from +12 to GND and to -12 also! As your suggestion I should put a 12ohm-12W resistor in the second circuit to continuously draw 1A from GND to -12. that's not good!

Answer (score 1):

If the current drawn from your +/-12V supplies is modest (some tens of mA for audio op-amps), or the current is *mostly* from +12 to -12), then you could use a rail-splitter IC such as the [TLE2426](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tle2426.pdf), which is essentially your op-amp circuit but with stability guaranteed with capacitive loading. Since your power supplies are obviously capable of a lot more current, you'll have to analyze what happens if the supply gets shorted momentarily. You should rate all parts to withstand a GND that could be shorted to +12 or -12.

It's possible to use an op-amp and add stabilization parts, too, but the circuit you've shown is likely to oscillate with real loads.

If your power supply current requirements are modest and if you use a second 24V supply you can use linear regulators (eg. 7812/7912) to reduce the +-24 to +-12 and be rid of most of the switching power supply noise, which would be better for audio.

Comment: Thanks Spehro! so let's assume i want to have 1A current assurance from +12 to GND and to -12 also! As your suggestion in the comment I should put a (12 ohm - 12 W) resistor in the second circuit to continuously draw 1A from GND to -12. that's not good!
TLE2426 has just about 20mA current output and that's not enough! Is there anything else that i could give it a shot?